# Storing files uploaded from Ubuntu on a Windows file server

Tags: ubuntu, file-upload, active-directory, laravel-5.5

I am writing an application to help manage our library. Digital versions of the documents should be uploaded to server and then be available for download by users.

I use Laravel 5.5 on a Ubuntu 16.04 Server and I want to store the uploaded files on our Active Directory file server.

How would I go about this? I did find out that I can use the Laravel filesystems, but I can't seem to find info on how to use Windows as disk.

I have been writing PHP code for over 15 years now, but never did file uploads, let alone upload to a different operating system. My searches didn't get me anywhere, maybe I'm not using the right keywords.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem configuration file is located at `config/filesystems.php`. Within this file you may configure all of your "disks". Each disk represents a particular storage driver and storage location.

You would have a local disk for default storage and a second disk representing the Windows server.  Choose an appropriate driver depending on how you will access the Windows server.  There is also a driver to connect via FTP (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#driver-prerequisites).

If your applications interacts with multiple disks, use the disk method on the Storage facade to work with files on a particular disk:

```
Storage::disk('windows')->put('avatars/1', $fileContents);

$file = Storage::disk('windows')->get('file.jpg');
```

From:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem